# Counting coloured pages in a PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I have adapted this code from another StackOverflow post. It converts a PDF page to an Image and checks the Hue/Saturation values for colour. My only issue is that it is very slow, almost takes a minute for 25 pages. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make it more efficient?

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import numpy as np

def main():
    images = convert_from_path("example1.pdf", 500,poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin')
    sw=0
    color=0

    for image in images:
        img = np.array(image.convert('HSV'))
        hsv_sum = img.sum(0).sum(0)
        if hsv_sum[0] == 0 and hsv_sum[1] == 0:
            sw += 1
        else:
            color += 1
    print(color)
    print(sw)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dpi=500` is going to make unnecessarily large demands on your memory if you are just trying to coarsely detect (probably large) regions of colour.

I would try `dpi=72` or even `dpi=36` and see if it is still accurate enough.

Further than that, if you are trying to speed things up it is important to measure what is slow - no point speeding up some aspect of your processing that only takes 1% of the time. So, measure how long it takes to convert all the PDF pages to `PIL Image` and then measure the time for analysing each page so that you know where to direct your efforts.

If the pages take a long time each to process, consider doing the pages in parallel.

Comment: That is actually a very valid point, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
import PyPDF2

pdf_file = open('nama_file.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

colored_page_count = 0

for page in pdf_reader.pages:
  if page.get("/ColorSpace") == "/DeviceRGB":
    colored_page_count += 1

print(colored_page_count)

pdf_file.close()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your post. It seems much faster but isn't picking up the color pages. Any idea why? It doesn't seem to be going into this if statement if page.get("/ColorSpace") == "/DeviceRGB":
            colored_page_count += 1

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

Depending on what exactly is colored in the page, you could use `borb` to get this done.

`borb` has the concept of `EventListener`, which gets notified of rendering instructions (as they are coming out of the parser).

This should be as fast as simply reading the PDF.

edit: based on your comment, I am including links to the following examples.

1. [Filtering text by its font color](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#582-filtering-by-font_color)
2. [Retrieving all embedded images from a PDF](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#59-extracting-images-from-a-pdf)

These examples might seem lengthy, but they are complete (in the sense that they will first create the PDF to later extract content/information from)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I guess coloured text and embedded images would be what I'd ideally like to look out for. Do you have any examples you know of that are similar to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide links to the official documentation, which includes examples of what you're asking for.